# Bulk Insert Optimization in .NET / EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have some .NET Core code that does some bulk loading of the DB with random sample data.

I'm getting 20 inserts/second on localhost, and looking to improve my performance.  I'm doing the basic stuff like calling `_dbContext.SaveChanges()` only once, etc.

A number of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600295/ef-codefirst-bulk-insert) indicate gains can be had by manipulating properties on the DbContext's Configuration, such as `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and `Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled`.

My .NET Core MVC app's DbContext is a subclass of `IdentityDbContext`, which does not expose the Configuration.

Not sure what approach I should be using - can I / should I be messing with those configuration properties of a IdentityDbContext subclass?

Or, should I use a separate DbContext for this? (Some early research indicated the typical pattern is a single DbContext for a webapp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for creating separated `DbContext` class and you can turn change tracking off:

`context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

or you can turn it off globaly:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext
{
   public MyContext()
    {
         ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }
}
```